# Как вытащить данные из json на php

Tags: php, массивы

Всем привет, такой вопрос: как проверять массив?

Пример массива:

```php
    <?php
    $array = array(
        'menu' => array(
            'Сообщества' => group()
        ),

        'group' => array(
            'edit' => array(
                'Назад' => function()
            )
        )
    );
    ?>
```

от вк приходит текст ( который написал пользователь ), 
пример: `Назад`.
и вот такой вопрос: как мне добраться до `Назад`? ( `group => edit => Назад`)

Примерный код:

```
<?php
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    ...
    if($key == $text)
    {
        MessagesSend($value);
    }
}
?>
```

`$text - это текст сообщения`

`... - это тот код который я не знаю как сделать.`

`в if не обьязательно проверять на $key можно и на $value`

`MessagesSend - это function которая отправляет вк данные!`
`В () я указал $value - это ответ на сообщение если оно найдено`

Comment: Покажите Ваш массив и результат, который хотите получить.

Comment: вы пишите про json, вот и приведите json, а не текст какой-то

Comment: @СлаваНосков [?](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d78fda562a67365164f9b8364deb1fdcd619beb2)

Comment: `Но если у меня массив в массиве несколько раз?` рекурсия?

Comment: А какая задача то? Найти какой-то уникальный массив? Найти самый вложенный?

Answer (score 1):

Используй `is_array()` для проверки, является ли `$value` массивом